# Issue while trying to copy pyside object

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, copy, pyside

I am having a rather frustrating problem using ***pyside*** and I would welcome any advice.

**First, some context**

I have created a simple GUI using ***Qt Designer*** and I have used `pyside-uic.exe` onto my `.ui` file in order to generate the associated ***Python*** file.

I am using ***Python 3.3*** and ***pyside 1.2.1*** with ***Qt Designer 4*** (***Qt 4.8.5***).

I am using the following code to launch my GUI:

```
class my_dialog(QMainWindow, my_gui.Ui_main_window):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(my_dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

if ("__main__" == name):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_dialog = my_dialog()

    # (1)

    main_dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**What I would like to achieve**

My GUI features several tabs. The number of tabs is not pre-determined and is evaluated at run time. As a result, I've decided to create one tab in ***Qt Designer***, to use as a template.

The first time I need to add a tab, I modify this template, and if I need any additionnal tab, I was planning on ***making a copy of that tab*** and then ***modify that copy*** appropriately.

**The issue I have encountered**

My problem is that I can't seem to find a way to copy the tab widget. After some research, I thought the [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/copy.html) module (or the [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pickle.html) module, see edit) might do the trick (the following code was inserted at ***(1)***):

```
new_tab = copy.deepcopy(main_dialog.my_tab)
main_dialog.my_tabs.addTab(new_tab, "")
```

But that triggered the following error:

> ```
>     main_dialog.my_tabs.addTab(new_tab, "")
> ```
>
> RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (Pyside.QtGui.QWidget) already deleted

**What I could find on my own**

I have seen on SO and other sites that there may be issues, when using ***pyside***, of objects being collected because there is no reference to them in ***Python***.

The fact remains, however, that even if I move this code to very `setupUi()` method in the `.py` file generated by ***pyside***, I still get the exact same error.

It is also worth noting that I am able to access the `my_tab` object to modify its content without any trouble.

I am able to create another tab from scratch in my code and `main_dialog.my_tabs.addTab(new_tab, "")` works perfectly fine in that context.

After some experimentations, I realized the problem probably occurs at the copy of the `my_tab` object. Indeed, copying a tab object that I just created, I could see that trying to add the copy to the GUI tabs failed too, and with the same error.

It looks like the copy fails somehow, or the object is being immediately deleted for some reason. That's what I'm infering anyway...

**My question**

Considering all this, I would like to find a way to either succeed in the object copy, find another way to use an existing ***pyside*** object as template for other similar objects.

I ***could*** of course take the code for the tab out of the generated file and code my own `addTab()` method. However, I am expected to build from an existing `.ui` file and avoid hardcoding GUI elements.

**EDIT:**

When using `pickle`:

```
new_tab = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(main_dialog.my_tab, -1))
```

I get the following error:

> ```
>     new_tab = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(main_dialog.my_tab, -1))
> ```
>
> _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'Pyside.QtCore.SignalInstance'>: attribute lookup Pyside.QtCore.SignalInstance failed.

Comment: What bothers me the most is that while `pickle` or `marshal` do tell me explicitly that they can't process the object, `copy` seems to work, doesn't raise any exception, but the object just isn't there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion of creating a separate ui file for the widget you want to copy seems a reasonable solution. Although it would seem that generating a separate gui module for the widget using pyside-uic would work just as well as using `QUiLoader` (in fact, it would be slightly more efficient).

As for the question of why cloning widget using e.g. `copy.deepcopy` doesn't work: this is because it will only copy the python wrapper, and not the underlying C++ object. A somewhat fuller explanation can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22726804/984421).

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, I believe copying a pyside object using one of those techniques is not possible.

The first thing to note is that [there is no built-in function to clone a Qt widget](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_clone_a_widget), so the cloning should be done using modules like `copy`, `pickle` or `marshal`.

Using `pickle` or `marshal` fails because the object is found to be *not pickable*.

Whilst the `copy.copy` or `copy.deeepcopy` do not raise any warning/exception/error, the copy does not occur, or is deleted right afterwards for some reason.

When trying to pass in the `deepcopy` as parameter to `addTab`, no warning/exception/error is thrown, yet the program stops at that line and exits back to the Python command prompt. The fact that it takes a few seconds on that line before exiting makes me assume `deepcopy` tries to browse through the object attributes and fails at some point. Doing the same with `copy` results in the previous `C++ object deleted` error mentionned in the question, so I can only infer the `deepcopy` operation does fail.

As a result, the only advice I could give someone looking for a similar answer is to implement their own `copy-widget` function, which is ultimately what I will do now.

Still, I wish to understand how is that `deepcopy` fails like this, so silently, yet provoking the end of the execution. I started a thread to try and find an answer to this [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707756/python-copy-deepcopy-fails-without-raising-warning-exception-or-error)

**EDIT:**

I found a solution for this problem, that respects my requirements of not hard-coding GUI elements and of using Qt Designer to create the GUI and templates for repeatable elements. I hope it helps anyone having the same issue:

The idea is that it is possible using Qt -- and pyside -- to load a given `.ui` file at run time, using the `QUiLoader()` method. It is thus possible to parse the `.ui` file to extract a given widget (`.ui` files are simple XML files) and use the following code to use it:

```
loader = QUiLoader()
ui_file = QFile("path_to_ui_file.ui")
ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
new_tab = loader.load(ui_file)
ui_file.close()
main_dialog.my_tabs.addTab(new_tab, "")
```

And it works!

A few things about the above example:

- the second line assumes you've isolated your widget in the file `path_to_ui_file.ui`
- in my example the widget is a tab, of course it works with any widget you might have done, the last line is only provided to show that the error is no longer thrown
- finally, this approach has the pro of allowing you to use tools like Qt Designer to develop your GUI elements even when some variables are involved, such as *just how many of that tabs do you want?*

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution to the main problem which was to use Qt Designer for the main window and for template widgets planned to be used in several instances in the application.